# Strong Parameters not working in Rails Model static method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I can find loads of information about working with and permitting strong parameters in a Controller, but what about when you are trying to update a model from within a model's static method?

I have the following code inside my OodleListing model in a method called self.update_listings, and it doesn't seem to work.

```
# Update DB values with updated values
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(oodle_listing.attributes.except('id', 'updated_at', 'created_at')).permit!
if existing_listings[0].update!(params)
  puts "Updated #{oodle_listing.oodle_id} - #{oodle_listing.title}"
else
  puts "Error: Unable to update #{oodle_listing.oodle_id} - #{oodle_listing.title}"
  puts " - #{oodle_listing.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}"
end
```

*(existing_listings[0] is a oodle_listing record that I retrieved using a OodleListing.where() query)*

It prints this in the console

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for OodleListing: oodle_id, title, body, url, source_id, source_name, address, zip, city_code, city_id, state_id, country_id, latitude, longitude, img1_src, img1_width, img1_height, img1_desc, img1_size, img2_src, img2_width, img2_height, img2_desc, img2_size, ctime, paid, revenue_score, currency, delivery, fee, breed_id, age, price, price_display, seller_phone, sex, color, discipline_id, last_compared
    app/models/oodle_listing.rb:98:in `block (2 levels) in update_listings'
    app/models/oodle_listing.rb:33:in `each'
    app/models/oodle_listing.rb:33:in `block in update_listings'
    app/models/oodle_listing.rb:15:in `update_listings'
```

However, immediately after it says COMMIT, despite no updates being saved

```
(109.5ms)  COMMIT
```

The only reference I could find is a snippet in the Strong Parameters GitHub page ( https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#use-outside-of-controllers ), which I've followed pretty much to the letter, but still no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: By using `permit!`, you're defeating the whole purpose. If you're just going to `permit!` the entire thing regardless of what is in there, **don't use strong params in the first place!** Just use `existing_listings[0].update!(oodle_listing.attributes.except(...))`

Comment: That's basically what I'd like to do, but the problem is that I can't figure out how not to use strong params in the first place!
It seems that whatever I do it comes up with the whole 'these params are invalid' warnings..